# Install PHP 7.1 on MacOS Sierra

Tags: php, macos, apache, configuration

I am using homebrew. I installed php 7.1. I added

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

to httpd.conf file. And also i added

```
<IfModule php7_module>
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
 AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

 <IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
 </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

to httpd.conf. There is phpinfo.php file on the folder. When i type locahost i can see "It works". but when i type localhost/phpinfo.php there is no result.

What did i forget?  Or you can give an article which i can follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. If you face this problem, and you sure about that you did everything right, just restart the computer.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to restart Apache (httpd) to make the configuration changes take effect. Restarting your computer does that, but you can also run in Terminal:

`sudo apachectl restart`